Hit `<foo>_pb.js` does not provide an export named `'<foo>'` syntax error
I generate proto js files with:
npx grpc_tools_node_protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./grpc/client --grpc_out=grpc_js:./grpc/client --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin` -I ./grpc/proto ./grpc/proto/*.proto && npx protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=`which protoc-gen-ts` --ts_out=grpc_js:./grpc/client -I ./grpc/proto ./grpc/proto/*.proto

These are the generated artefacts:

I don't see any error when building the typescript project. However, when I run I hit this error:
$ export PORT=4433&&n run start

> node.jsrestapi@1.0.0 start
> export NODE_ENV=development&& node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node build/src/webapi/server.js

file:///usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/build/src/webapi/Services/SchoolService.js:5
import { CommonStudentsResponse as grpcCommonStudentsResponse, } from "../grpc/client/school_pb.js";
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module '../grpc/client/school_pb.js' does not provide an export named 'CommonStudentsResponse'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:171:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:254:5)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:475:24)
    at async asyncRunEntryPointWithESMLoader (node:internal/modules/run_main:109:5)

Node.js v22.2.0

I see the symbol being defined in the file in question:

What do I miss?
Environment

OS name, version and architecture: [e.g. Linux Ubuntu 18.04 amd64] Ubuntu 24.04
Node version [e.g. 8.10.0] 22.2.0
Node installation method [e.g. nvm] apt
If applicable, compiler version [e.g. clang 3.8.0-2ubuntu4] g++ 13.2.0
Package name and version [e.g. gRPC@1.12.0]:

    "grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts": "^5.3.3",
    "@grpc/grpc-js": "^1.10.10",
    "@grpc/proto-loader": "^0.7.13",


Please don't use images for text particularly when it's trivial to copy-paste the text into the question. Images may not outlive questions and inhibit our ability to use their content when responding.

You don't include your protobuf sources and I'm not familiar with Protobuf in JavaScript but it appears the export is proto.school.CommonStudentsResponse not CommonStudentsResponse. Is this the issue?
